# UINavigation controller doesn't open in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I am loading a `UIViewController` the following way:

```
-(void)logIn
{
    NewSignInView *viewController = [[[NewSignInView alloc] init] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [navController release];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{ self.view.alpha = 0; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
}
```

`NewSignView` is a `UIViewController` that creates a `UITableView` to get the input from the user. When I load it using a `UINavigationController` it refuses to open in Landscape mode. But if I load it directly to `CCDirector` the following way it opens properly in landscape.

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:viewController.view];
```

I use the following inside `NewSignInView`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

So something is preventing the `UINavigationController` from opening up in landscape mode. Can anyone help me in any way on trying to figure out what is causing the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try following in your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
```

So your Controller supports both rotations, not only LandscapeRight.
Make sure the ViewController with the logIn-Method returns YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Hope this helps.
Besides i would make one suggestion: Don't name your ViewController NewSignInView with out Controller to avoid confusion. If it was only a quick and diry example - never mind.

greets